# MySQL Query JOINS are not retrieving fully

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

On my website I am trying to program a feature, similar to facebook and twitters timeline, where a user can 'follow' another user, and receive their 'broadcast'. The database tables are:

```
**members**
--------
id
fullname
following

**broadcasts**
-----------
id
mem_id
broadcast (the content)
broadcast_date
```

"following" in the members table is a varchar text that stores user ID's. So if I'm following users 4 5 and 6 (4,5,6,) would appear in the following column. My problem is, what I'm querying from the database, it's only retrieving the 'broadcasts' from the first user that I am following and no other user else.

```
$sql_broadcasts = mysql_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM members 
        JOIN broadcast 
            ON(broadcast.mem_id = members.following)
    WHERE members.id=$id
    ORDER BY broadcast_date DESC
    LIMIT 10;
");
```

where $id is $_SESSION['id']. I've been staring at this code for a long time, can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Whats this legendary follower_array? Not mentioned in the field listing...

Comment: The table description is scarcely readable. Is everything on one side of the "|" supposed to be in one table? Much better is to use SQL schema statements (`CREATE TABLE`) to show table structure. [Source code rules](http://sscce.org/). As a'r mentions, you should be using prepared statements with parameters rather than interpolating values directly into statements. Prepared statements are easier, more secure and more performant.

Comment: what's type of member.id ( integer or varchar ) ?

Answer (score 3):

Joins do not work that way.

Assuming that broadcast.mem_id is a numeric type the database will silently cast members.follower_array; this will make 4 from 4,5,6, so one record matches.

You will need a m:n relation for this to work, one table with members (which you already have); and another table with followers, for each follower you insert a record which contains the member id of the member who is being and the member id of the member who is following. That way a member can have 0-n followers.

```
Table member
id

Table follower
member_id
member_id_follower
```

Then you can do something like

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
   member AS mb
JOIN
   follower AS fl ON fl.member_id = mb.id
WHERE
   mb.id = 123
```

Comment: +1 : Agreed.  The OP's description of the `following` field shows a possible mis-understanding of relational databases design.  The use of a mapping table makes much sense.

Comment: Yes, this is the proper way to do this. Nevertheless it is probably possible (albeit probably horribly inefficient) to replace the equality test in the JOIN with some kind of list membership test.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to get all following ids in sub query and passing it to parent one!

```
$sql_broadcasts = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM broadcast where mem_id IN( Select following from members where id = $id)
ORDER BY broadcast_date DESC
LIMIT 10;
");
```

where following filed contains all following ids comma split e.g 4,5,6